# Timeout on mouse enter and leave

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an unordered list, which changes position when hovering each child element. If I don't put a timeout on mouseover it jumps quickly through the list due to the position changing. What I've noticed is when hovering one li then jumping to the next li, the timeout doesn't finish. I have to leave the li element, wait then re-hover for the timeout to cancel.

I want to be able to hover each li element to update the ul position, but with a timeout so it's not constantly jumping through the list.

I'm open to other suggestions, if this isn't the best way around resolving this.

[image: Preview of unordered list, which starts at the bottom of the page then moved up or down depending on ul position when hovering li.]

```
var time, allow = true;
$("ul").children("li").each(function(index) {
    $(this).on('mouseover', function() {
        if(allow == true) {
            var i = index + 1;
            var calc = $('ul').height() / $('ul').children("li").length * i;
            $("ul").css('transform', 'translate(-50%, -'+ calc +'px)');
            allow = false;
        }
    }).mouseout(function () {
        time = setTimeout(function () {
            allow = true;
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Update: When leaving the current element then hovering the next element the 'allow' isn't finishing the mouseout delay.

```
var time, allow = true;

$("ul").children("li").each(function(index) {

    $(this).find('a').mouseover(function() {
        if(allow == true) {
            allow = false;
            var i = index + 1;
            var calc = $('ul').height() / $('ul').children("li").length * i;
            $("ul").css('transform', 'translate(-50%, -'+ calc +'px)');
        }
    });

    $(this).mouseout(function () {
        time = setTimeout(function () {
            allow = true;
        }, 1000);
    });

});
```

Comment: What about simply cancelling the timer in `mouseover`? That is only if you want the timer to be global. If each `<li>` element should have its own timer, you should probably store a dictionary/map of the timers.

Answer (score 0):

`.bind()` is deprecated, so if you dont have to for compatibility reasons, use `.on()` instead.

Nevertheless what you do is calling `.mouseout()` on the return value of `bind()`. There is [no documented return value](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_bind.asp)
for `bind` or `on`, so you should probably make a separate call like so and while your at it just use the shorthands [mouseover()](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and [mouseout()](https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) both times:

```
$("ul").children("li").each(function(index) {
    $(this).mouseover(function() {
        if(allow == true) {
            // do stuff
            allow = false;
        }
    })
    $(this).mouseout(function () {
        time = setTimeout(function () {
            allow = true;
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```